# stack array implementation, returning size of array

Tags: java, arrays, count, stack, implementation

I am trying to find the number of elements in a stack (I am implementing an array). So far I have

```
   int size = 0;
   while( top != -1 ){
   size++;
   pop();
}
   return size;

}
```

This works perfectly by giving me the size, however I do not want to empty my array. How can I do fix my code in order to do this?

Comment: Why don't you maintain an instance `size` field?

Comment: You need to keep size or top index anyway, how else would push/pop work?

Comment: i want to do it all within this method

Comment: Please post the whole class, so that we can see how your implementation works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll suggest the following approach, according to what I understood.
Don't just remove the topmost element within the pop() method just reduce the value of the pointer to the topmost element of the stack.

```
private int pointerToTheTopmostElement = 0; // increase when pushed, decrease when poped

public int pop(){
    int popingElement = pointerToTheTopmostElement;
    pointerToTheTopmostElement--;
    return stack[popingElement];
}
```

Something like this might do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I undestood your question correctly, but if you want to find out how many objects you have in a collection, you could for eg:

```
for(int i=0; i=<theNameOfYourArray.size(); i++){
    System.out.println("Size of collection currently is: " + i);
}
```

Then just check the output for the last value of i.

Comment: The last printed value of `i` will be `theNameOfYourArray.size()`, there is no point in doing the loop.

Comment: @Cinnam heh my skills really seem to be getting rusty :D I guess my method would only be helpful if he needed to do something for each element in the collection, but thats another case..